# Merging two export statements into single export in one file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, yaml, export

I am integrating a YAML plugin in my application using:

```
npm install react-i18next --save
```

Here the exporting is in a different YAML export:

```js
export default withNamespaces()(App))
```

I am also using export in my existing project like this:

```js
const connectedSeystemConfigScreen = connect(mapStateToProps)(SystemConfig);
export { connectedSeystemConfigScreen as SystemConfig };.
```

How can I combine these two exports?